# virtual host setup laravel xampp

Tags: apache, laravel, virtualhost, virtual-hosts

I am trying to set up virtual host with xampp for my laravel project. I have done following changes.

on httpd.conf

```
Listen 8080
# Virtual hosts
Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
```

I normally access my localhost files using localhost:8080 port

on httpd-vhosts.conf

```
    NameVirtualHost *:8080
<VirtualHost *:8080>
    ServerAdmin admin@abounde.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/code/customer_portal/public"
    ServerName abounde.com
    ErrorLog "logs/abounde.log"
    #CustomLog "logs/dummy-host2.example.com-access.log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

edited hosts file from windows/system32/drivers/etc/hosts

and added following

```
127.0.0.1           abounde.com
```

I restarted the server after saving all changes. 
I pinged abounde.com and found the domain points to 127.0.0.1 which means its working.

However when i try to access abounde.com the localhost based site do not load

[image]

Any way to diagnosis the problem?

Comment: Are you accessing `http://abounde.com:8080` ??

Comment: yes.. do i need to use 80 to be able to use abounde.com ?

Comment: hey man..solved it...changed the port to 80.

Comment: For future references Nurul, whenever you're replying a comment, you should tag the person with an `@` like @Zak, otherwise the person is not notified about your reply and may never answer you again. You are automatically notified because you created the question.

Comment: @MarcoAurélioDeleu ok

Comment: Great, you did it!